# finding the index of an element in relation to a specific parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

Looking at the example here - http://jsfiddle.net/uqYeQ/3/

The first row behaves as expected, returning the index of the div within it's parent.

I'd like the 2nd row to behave in the same way, I'd like it to return between 0 and 4 depending on which div has been clicked. I'd like to know the index of the div that has been clicked in relation to it's parent list item.

I cannot change the html at all.

Comment: sorry, where is the second row in your fiddle?

Comment: ooops, I was looking in chrome. hang on.

Comment: or I gave the wrong url. question edited.

Comment: You'll have to write some code to do that; the `.index()` function specifically gives you the index of an element in its parent's list of elements. In your second row, you've got those "container" `<div>` elements, so that's what `.index()` counts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a whirl ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uqYeQ/6/))

```
$("li > .myclass, li > .container").click(function(e){
    $("#result").html($(this).index());            
});
```

​

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uqYeQ/7/))

```
$('.myclass').click(function(){
   var theIndex = $(this).index();
   $('#result').html(theIndex);
})

$('.container').click(function(){
    var theIndex = $(this).index();
    $('#result').html(theIndex);
})
```

but antisanity's is sexier.

Answer (score 0):

The following is one approach

```
$('.myclass').click(function() {
    var liElem = $(this).parents('li')[0]; // get li element who is a parent of the clicked element
    var elems = $(this).parents();
    elems.push($(this)); //array contains all parents of the clicked element and the clicked element
    $(elems).each(function(key, elem) {
        if ($(elem).parent()[0] == $(liElem)[0]) {
            $('#result').html($(elem).index());
        }
    });
})
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R5MkJ/3/)